# Unable to push changes to remote branch in git

Tags: git

As part of my development process, I created a local branch and then started making changes to the code and committed the file. When I push the changes for the first time, a new branch is created on the remote site. Next time I make the changes to the code in my local branch, I would like to push these changes to the remote branch. Problem here is that the master has moved forward by some more commits before I push my local changes and when I try to do a push, I get a message that the remote branch is behind master and the push is rejected. How do I do this?

Comment: Commit & Push your changes to remote. `git commit -am 'Message'`, `git push origin HEAD`. Are you getting any error ?

Comment: Push to your branch using "git push origin <your-branch>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the remote version of the branch you are working on is ahead of your local version, you first

- have to pull the changes, 
  `git pull origin yourBranch`

  - As a warning, you might have some conflict at this point, if so you'd need to resolve them, and then do a commit, otherwise you'd commit conflicted files. You would get a warning when you do the `pull`, or check by yourself by doing `git status`
- commit your changes on top of it, 
  `git commit -am "msg"`
- and finally push to origin;
  `git push origin yourBranch`

Also, be sure that your current branch (`HEAD`) is `yourBranch` otherwise you might modify other branches, check by `git branch`, and confirm that is your branch is the active one.

As long as the remote `yourBranch` has not pulled `master` branch by someone, you should be able to work independent from `master` in your `yourBranch`

Comment: Actually, it's the remote 'master' that has forwarded, my remote branch is still behind my local branch.

Comment: That wouldn't affect your branch though, you can work independent of your master branch, when you do a push to remote of your branch

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using `git push` to push your code. This causes git to push all the branches, including the master branch which is behind the remote version. To push only your development branch use `git push origin <branch name>` or just `git push origin HEAD` which would push your current branch.

Note: I'm assuming your remote is called 'origin'.

Answer (score 1):

Run `git stash` to save your local changes to a stack.

```
git stash
git checkout master
git stash pop  /*or git apply (pop removes stash)*/
```

merge your changes and commit them again:

```
git commit -am "msg"
git push origin master
```